# SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, routes

I'm a newbie with linux and I have a problem I don't know how to resolve...
I needed to add the routing table to my device with this command:

````
```sudo ifconfig wlan0mon up 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1```
````

I get this:

````
```SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted```
````

What can I do to unlock this command?

So I did find two possible solutions and tried them but for the first command I get:

```
Code
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/fap]
└─$ sudo docker exec --privileged container ip route add default via 192.168.1.0 dev eth0 130 ⨯
sudo: docker: command not found
```

With the second method I get:

```
Code
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/fap]
└─$ pid=($sudo docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container) 127 ⨯

sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns
sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid

sudo ip netns exec $pid ip route add default via 192.168.1.0
ln: target 'container': No such file or directory
Cannot open network namespace "docker": No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to add this route on the host?

Comment: yes this 

ifconfig wlan0mon up 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1

Comment: Then try adding `--net host` to make sure you are running the container in host network ns

Comment: can you write me the code? Sorry I'm not very practical...

Comment: Seems like you don't have docker and you don't need it. Run the 2nd command also with `sudo`. `sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

There are two commands that you are running. One with sudo and one without. So you should run both of them with sudo

```sh
sudo ifconfig wlan0mon up 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```